# Oracle DB comparing two rows

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have data of coordinates x, y in my DB, and I'm trying to `SELECT` only the points that satisfies `(previous_y_value - x) * (current_y_value - x) < 0` when `x` is a given y value.

Also, this table is humongous. So it takes too long to `SELECT` from a table you build with `LAG` function.

I've been trying everything for a whole day, but still haven't figured it out.

Is this possible with one `SELECT`?

If not, what other ways are there?

Thank you. :D

Comment: Good Luck.  There might be a way to eeek out some performance gains using analytic functions.  What RDBMS?

Comment: Please define "humongous" in terms of number of rows.

Comment: Also, if the only thing you have to SELECT on is the relationship stated, the query will have to do a full table scan anyways. Is there nothing else that can be used to filter this query?

Comment: Can you use PL/SQL? What is the sort order? Can we have a little more information about the table and the search criteria?

Comment: You say you have x & y coordinates.  You give a formula that involves `x` but then say that the `x` in your formula is "a given y value".  So the `x` in your formula isn't the `x` from your coordinates?  If so, that's a bit confusing.  If that interpretation is correct, your formula comes down to `provided_y_value between least(previous_y_value, current_y_value) and greatest( previous_y_value, current_y_value)`, right?

Comment: You use the term "previous_y_value". How is "previous" determined?